# Toggle the display of a text field with a checkbox

Tags: javascript

When Unlimited is checked, remove the input box. That works. However, when the checkbox is unchecked the input box wont show back up.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getQuantity() {
        var checkbox = document.getElementById("unlimited");
        var qty = document.getElementById("quantityspace");
        if(checkbox.checked == true){
             qty.style.display = 'none';
        }else if(checkbox.checked == false) {
             qty.stlye.display = '<input type="text" id="quantity" size="4" value="1" name="quantity" />';
        }
    }
</script>

<input type="checkbox" id="unlimited" name="unlimited" value="x" onClick="getQuantity(); " /> Unlimited? <span id="quantityspace">or specify:
<input type="text" id="quantity" size="4" value="1" name="quantity" /></span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
qty.stlye.display = '<input type="text" id="quantity" 
size="4" value="1" name="quantity" />';
```

should be:

```
qty.style.display = 'inline'; // or block
```

`display` is a property of the **already existing** input tag.  You don't need to assign the entire tag to the property to make it show up again -- in fact that's dead wrong.  Simply assign that property a new *valid* value for display, like `inline`, `inline-block` or `block` and it will show up again.

Comment: it should *really* be style :)

Comment: @froadie - We both saw it at the same time ;-) Thanks!

Comment: I corrected what I *thought* was a typo in the first code block. Having looked at the question, I'm not sure any more that it was a typo. Um, have a look? Sorry if I screwed up =/

Comment: @David -- no problem. It *was* a typo (your eyes did not deceive you) ... in the OP's code. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In your `else if(...)` you have:

```
qty.stlye.display
```

Do you mean `style`?

Additionally, you're incorrectly defining the display attribute. It should be a [valid value](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp). You probably want it to be:

```
else if(!checkbox.checked) {
    qty.style.display = 'inline'; // or something from the W3C link above
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it just that you've misspelled 'qty.stlye.display'?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `qty.stlye.display` line to:

```
qty.style.display = "";
```

Note that you misspelled "style" there.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled "style" as "stlye" and you're setting the display style to HTML for some reason. It should be 'inline' or 'block' or whatever it was before you set it to 'none'.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this:

```
function getQuantity() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("unlimited");
    var qty = document.getElementById("quantityspace");
    if(checkbox.checked == true){
        qty.innerHTML = '';
    }else if(checkbox.checked == false) {
        qty.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="quantity" size="4" value="1" name="quantity" />';
     }
}
```

If I'm correct, you want to put an input in the `quantityspace` element when the checkbox is not checked.

`qty.style.display` changes the CSS `display` property of the span. `qty.innerHTML` changes the HTML inside the span.

You could do it with `.style.display` with the following code:

```
function getQuantity() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("unlimited");
    var qty = document.getElementById("quantityspace");
    if(checkbox.checked == true){
        qty.style.display= 'none';
    }else if(checkbox.checked == false) {
        qty.style.display= 'inline';
     }
}
```